# Weird error in existing Crypto++ code, casting pointers to void*

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers, crypto++, reinterpret-cast

I'm getting a weird casting error when compiling with Crypto++
(The Crypto++ source code is directly `#include`'d by my application, in the same assembly.
All the Crypto++ `*.cpp` source files are added to CMake and directly compiled. This usually works fine.)

```
/*******************************************
** Snippet of unedited Crypto++ source code:
**     misc.h
*******************************************/

template <class T>
inline void SecureWipeArray(T *buf, size_t n)
{
    if (sizeof(T) % 8 == 0 && GetAlignmentOf<T>() % GetAlignmentOf<word64>() == 0)
        SecureWipeBuffer(reinterpret_cast<word64 *>(static_cast<void *>(buf)), n * (sizeof(T)/8)); //error
    else if (sizeof(T) % 4 == 0 && GetAlignmentOf<T>() % GetAlignmentOf<word32>() == 0)
        SecureWipeBuffer(reinterpret_cast<word32 *>(static_cast<void *>(buf)), n * (sizeof(T)/4)); //error
    else if (sizeof(T) % 2 == 0 && GetAlignmentOf<T>() % GetAlignmentOf<word16>() == 0)
        SecureWipeBuffer(reinterpret_cast<word16 *>(static_cast<void *>(buf)), n * (sizeof(T)/2)); //error
    else
        SecureWipeBuffer(reinterpret_cast<byte *>(static_cast<void *>(buf)), n * sizeof(T)); //error
}
```

All four lines give the same error:

> 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'T *' to 'void *'
> 'CryptoPP::SecureWipeBuffer': no matching overloaded function found

I'm compiling with C++20, but that shouldn't cause breaking problems when compiling pre-C++20 code, right?

I wrote a "SecArray" class that inherits `std::array` and uses `SecureWipeArray` when the object is destroyed.
*(Side note: should the destructor be virtual? `std::array` doesn't have any destructors)*

```
namespace myNamespace
{

    template<class T, size_t length>
    class array : public std::array<T, length>
    {
    private:
        using base = std::array<T, length>;

    public:
        inline ~array() noexcept
        {
            SecureWipeArray(base::data(), length);
        }

        constexpr inline operator T* () noexcept { return base::data(); }
        constexpr inline operator T const* () const noexcept { return base::data(); }
    };
}
```

This is the only time my code invokes `SecureWipeArray` directly.
(I also wrote some container classes that use `std` containers with `CryptoPP::AllocatorWithCleanup`, which in turn invokes `SecureWipeArray`)

But `T` should still be a basic type, like `char`, `uint`, `string`, etc.
So I'm not sure what is causing this error.
Where should I look for the potential cause?

Comment: The error message should continue and say what type `T` is in the template expansion ?

Comment: @RichardCritten Apparently Microsoft Visual Studio doesn't provide that level of detail in the error, even when compiling CMake projects using Ninja? Is there a "verbose" option I should enable to get more error detail?

Comment: @rustyx No, that's a separate error. `SecureWipeBuffer` is a function being called, which the compiler can't understand without first getting past the `void*` issue.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. OHHH GENIUS. It's because I declared an `array<const char>` or something, somewhere. So I should use `conditional_t<is_const_v<...>...>` to check for const types as `T`, and `const_cast` as needed. Lemme try this out and see what happens. Thanks for the tip!!

Comment: Are you looking at the errors view or the compiler output view? Compiler output should show much more detail than that.

Comment: @rustyx lol I never look at the compiler output. That's probably a bad habit. Sure enough, it says `with[T=const char] ... note: Conversion loses qualifiers.` That other person nailed it. Not sure why they deleted their comment ...

Comment: I thought of `const array<int, 5>` first but then realized it's perfectly fine. What is not ok is `array<const int, 5>`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I solved it using a very unconventional method. (See answer below) Tell me if I'm crazy.

Comment: Stop looking at the stupid errors view.  It is s crappy "friendly" wrapper around what you need to know.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yeah, I see that now. XD

Answer (score 0):

If you have an std array that is const, any attempt to modify its contents is undefined behaviour.

This means your program's bahaviour, before and after the write, has no restrictions placed on it by the C++ standard.  Yes UB can cause time travel, and it does.

The most likely effects are the write not occuring, not all code sees the write (in an inconsitent manner), and/or the data is on a protected page or rom and your program or computer crashes.

Const data (as opposed to const pointers) in C++ is actually const.

If you want to do this, strip the const in the strange and provide a const interface to it.  Then what you want to do is legal.

Do not, however, use unions to type pun.  That is not legal in most cases in C++.

```
template<class T, size_t length>
struct array<T const, length> : private std::array<T, length>
{
  using base=std::array<T, length>;
  // then forward:
  T const*begin()const{return base::begin();}
  // etc
  array(std::array<T const, length> arr):base(arr){}
};
```

Comment: Using template specialization (and possibly inheritance) to handle const wrappers, is a way better approach than my crazy union idea. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.